# Issue returning a SOAP function using PHP

Tags: php, soap

Using this:

```
<?PHP
$client = new SoapClient('servername.wsdl');
$result = $client->GetUsersEmail(array('Password' => 
'mypassword',   'username' => 'myusername'));
var_dump ($result);
?>
```

I get this result:

> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["GetUsersEmailResult"]=> string(8) "myusername" }

There is another function - IsValidUser -
And when I replace "GetUsersEmail" with "IsValidUser" I get a correct value returned: true or false.p

Totally new to SOAP and I have no idea what I am missing.

The actual .wsdl is on an Intranet but here is a link to a copy.
http://www.awrensnest.com/sample.wsdl

Comment: The "problem" is that we cannot see inside the WSDL file. This file defines what structures / types are returned and what calls exist. It is entirely possible that both call returns are different than what you expect and that you are not missing anything. Only way to know is knowing whats inside servername.wsdl

Comment: added a link to a sample of the .wsdl

Answer (score 1):

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetUsersEmail">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http:/ / tempuri.org / IAuthenticationService / GetUsersEmail " message="tns: IAuthenticationService_GetUsersEmail_InputMessage "/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http: //tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/GetUsersEmailResponse" message="tns:IAuthenticationService_GetUsersEmail_OutputMessage"/>
```

You have to lookup the xsd definition for the output message, maybe it isnt set to string.

Comment: Turns out my code was fine and there was an issue with the Functions on the server.  thanks for your help.